# Azure - can't remove SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-sql

Something went wrong, I can't connect to Azure SQL server. I try to remove it
[image]

[image]
but get an error:

> Failed to delete the server: ***.  ErrorCode: 504  ErrorMessage:
>   {"error":{"code":"GatewayTimeout","message":"The gateway did not
>   receive a response from 'Microsoft.Sql' within the specified

Nothing more info. Just I see in notifications, that infinite restoring process of database, included in this SQL Server.

How can I remove SQL server forcibly?

**ADDED:**

Deleting is being during 10 hours

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the server is busy trying to complete your restore and so can't do anything else. You either need to wait for the restore to complete, or if it won't then contact support.